# DIV move animation doesn't work when pixel value is stored in variable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to move a DIV to the right and have an animation setup between my CSS and Javascript files. The animation works when I have the pixel value (345px) specifically typed in. However, my intent is to have a variable supplying the pixel value.

HTML code

```
<div id="gameContainer">
    <div class="boxes" id="greenBox"></div>
    <div class="boxes" id="blueBox"></div>
    <div class="boxes" id="redBox"></div>
    <div class="boxes" id="yellowBox"></div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary">Start</button>
```

CSS code

```
.boxes{
    transition: transform 1000ms;
}
```

JavaScript code

```
$("button").click(function(){
    // These 3 lines are used to get the pixel value in a variable.
    var pixelStored = document.getElementById("blueBox");
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(pixelStored);
    var leftValue = style.getPropertyValue("left");
   
    // This works.
    $("#redBox").css({top: leftValue});

    // This doesn't work.
    $("#greenBox").css("transform", "translateX(leftValue)");  

    // This also works.
    $("#greenBox").css("transform", "translateX(345px)"); 
});
```

The move with the "#redBox" div doesn't and isn't supposed to animate, but it does move with the 'leftValue' variable supplying the pixel value of 345px. I just used that as a test to see if the 345px value would work stored in a variable.
However, with my "#greenBox" transform code it doesn't work with the pixel value stored in the 'leftValue' variable. I'm assuming that this has to do with 'leftValue' being the wrong type.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're passing the string `translateX(leftValue)` to the css, and never referencing the variable itself. Using Javascript's template literals, you can insert the value of `leftValue` into the css property.

```js
$("#greenBox").css("transform", `translateX(${leftValue})`);
```

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  //THESE 3X LINES ARE USED TO GET THE PIXEL VALUE IN A VARIABLE
  var pixelStored = document.getElementById("blueBox");
  var style = window.getComputedStyle(pixelStored);
  var leftValue = style.getPropertyValue("left");


  $("#greenBox").css("transform", `translateX(${leftValue})`);


});
```

```css
.boxes {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: transform 1000ms;
}

#blueBox {
  left: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gameContainer">
  <div class="boxes" id="greenBox"></div>
  <div class="boxes" id="blueBox"></div>
  <div class="boxes" id="redBox"></div>
  <div class="boxes" id="yellowBox"></div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary">Start</button>
```

Comment: Thanks!!  I thought I tried template literals correctly, but didn’t include the ${} around the variable.  I’ll try this when I get home. Thanks again!

Comment: It worked!!  Thanks again!